# How do I determine if a certain amount of objects in an array contain the same property with the same value in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

images I have an array of objects `card`

```js
const card1 = {number: 1, color: 'red'}
const card2 = {number: 2, color: 'red'}
const card3 = {number: 3, color: 'red'}

const array = [card1, card2, card3]
```

I want to write a function to determine if a certain amount of the `card` in the array has the same color. For the case above the function should return `true`

My attempt is

```js
function hasSameColor(array) {
  let flag = true
  let prev
  for(const card of array) {
    if(prev && prev !== card.color) {
     flag = false
     break
   } 
    flag = card.color
}
  return flag
}
```

I wonder if there is any more concise and elegant way of writing this function?

And how do we extend the function to account for arbitrary numbers of object that contains the same property?

For example, what if we only ask for 2 objects' color to be the same, if so, we return `true`

The function would accept a second parameter to be the number of objects like this `function hasSameColor(array, N)`

My attempt is

```js
const fn = (cards, N) => {
      const colors = {}
      for(const card of cards) {
        colors[card.color] = (colors[card.color] || 0) + 1
      }

      return Object.values(colors).find(num => num >= N)
    }
```

Comment: `array.length === 0 || array.every(({color}) => color === array[0].color);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the es6 set operator it gets rid of duplicates. so if you have one after set they are all the same.

```
const card1 = {number: 1, color: 'red'}
const card2 = {number: 2, color: 'red'}
const card3 = {number: 3, color: 'red'}

const array = [card1, card2, card3]

const allSameColor = (new Set(array.map((x) => x.color)).size) === 1
```

https://medium.com/dailyjs/how-to-remove-array-duplicates-in-es6-5daa8789641c

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I tweaked my problem a bit where I wanted to parameterize the number of objects ti check.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES6 [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to do this cleanly:

```
function hasSameColor([first, ...rest]) {
  for(const element of rest) {
    if (element.color !== first.color) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```